# Enable / Disable Touch Events on UIImageView Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, touch

I've read answers to many questions that dealt with enabling / disabling touch events, but nothing has worked for me, so I'm asking one of my own.

I have a UIImageView object (`spot`):

```
// in my view controller header file:
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *spot;
```

Then I have code relating to this object:

```
// in my view controller .m file:
@synthesize spot

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    // handle when that spot is touched ... 
}
```

And that works fine.  For example, I can change the image displayed at the spot when the spot is clicked.

First I wanted to see how to disable touch events on the spot so I tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

And that works fine.  At certain points, depending on what I want to do, I was able to disable all touch events.

Then I added a button to this view controller and I want the button to be clickable ALWAYS, to have a touch event ALWAYS enabled for the button.

So now my approach to disabling touch events won't work because it's too heavy-handed.  It wipes out all touch events anywhere in that view.

I want to disable ONLY the touch event on that spot. I tried:

```
spot.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But that didn't work.  The spot was still clickable.  I also tried:

```
[spot1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Also didn't work.  I'm quite confused as to why those don't work.  My question is:

How can I disable touch events on just this one spot, this one UIImageView object?

**EDIT**: To address the question asked below, in the Interface Builder, in my .xib I have linked the UIImageView object to the property set in my header file.  That's its Referencing Outlet.

Comment: Where are you adding the gesture recognizer to spot?

Comment: In my .xib I have a UIImageView linked to the property set in my header file. It's attached to:  
`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *spot;`  
That's its Referencing Outlet.

Comment: Uncheck "User Interaction Enabled" in the interface designer of Xcode to disable any kind of interaction

Comment: In the interface designer, I deselected the "User Interaction Enabled" box in the Accessibility pane. The "User Interaction Enabled" box in the View pane was already deselected. Nothing worked. The spot is still clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to disable touch for your spot? You can simply skip handling if the touch was from the spot.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

     CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
     if (CGRectContainsPoint(spot.frame, touchLocation))
         return;

     if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, touchLocation)){
         //do something
     }
 }
```

Comment: So the case is that I *do* want to handle touch until a point. Then I want to disable touch. (It's a game.) So when the game starts, I have my `touchesBegan withEvent` method that handles touches correctly. But at a certain point - after that spot has been touched - touch needs to be disabled on the spot.

Comment: `BOOL spotWasTouched` maybe? :)

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting. Yes, I can tell when the spot was touched, so a `spotWasTouched` boolean won't help by itself. I'm asking what code is required to disable the ability to touch spots (`UIImageView` objects) at a certain point. So at any given point in the code, I can say "Hey, I no longer want to respond to touch on these certain `UIImageView` objects.

Comment: You can set a boolean variable at any point in your code. Then, in the `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event` method you can check this variable and ignore handling if the frame of touch mathes the frame of your spot and the value is true. If you want to enable touch processing again for spot, you need to set this variable to false. So, if the frame of touch doesn't match with the frame of spot touch handling will be enabled. And, if frames are equal, touch responding will depend on this variable.

Comment: Where I wrote: "frame of touch matches the frame of spot", you should read:"point of touch is contained in the frame of spot" :)

Comment: Okay, yes, now I understand what you were suggesting. That's actually the approach I ended up taking a few days ago when I couldn't figure anything else out. Seems like a decent solution.